# std::future<neither::Either<int, std::string>> segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++14, either

The code in this question uses the `Either<>` implementation found here: https://github.com/LoopPerfect/neither. To be clear, I doubt that this is a problem with this specific library, otherwise I would have created an issue there.

The following snippet works as expected:

```cpp
std::future<std::string> f = std::async(std::launch::async, []()
{
    return "test";
}

std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;
```

And the following generates a segmentation fault:

```cpp
std::future<neither::Either<int, std::string>> f = std::async(std::launch::async, []()
{
    return neither::Either<int, std::string>(neither::right(std::string("test")));
});

neither::Either<int, std::string> v = f.get(); // Segmentation fault
std::cout << v.right().value << std::endl;
```

Returning `left(-1)` works, as does `neither::Either<int, int>` for both `left()` and `right()`. I know that `std::future::get` might generate a segfault is that you've called it twice, in which case `std::future::valid` will return false just prior to calling `get`, but `valid` returns true.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there something I'm missing here?

The library isn't properly implemented. Specifically for the purposes of this question, the [copy constructor](https://github.com/LoopPerfect/neither/blob/e7e0b97a29e6d1aad80e4661bd2f151dfab66878/neither/include/either.hpp#L55) is wrong:

```
constexpr Either( Either<L, R> const& e )
  : isLeft(e.isLeft) {
  if(isLeft) {
    leftValue = e.leftValue;
  } else {
    rightValue = e.rightValue; // (*)
  }
}
```

We can't assign to `this->rightValue` there, there isn't a `std::string` in existence at that spot - we have uninitialized memory.

A correct copy constructor would be:

```
Either(Either<L, R> const& e)
  : isLeft(e.isLeft)
{
  if(isLeft) {
    new (&leftValue) L(e.leftValue);
  } else {
    new (&rightValue) R(e.rightValue);
  }
}
```

or, since we're writing generic library code that could be used by all sorts of evil types, you'll want:

```
::new (static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(leftValue))) L(e.leftValue);
```

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? The inside call is to `Either(Right<R> const&)`, which should construct `rightValue` prior to calling the copy constructor.

Comment: @DavidFreitag `e` is constructed properly, but `this` isn't. The starred line invokes `std::string::operator=(std::string const&)`, which requires a `std::string` to exist - but we don't have a `std::string`, we have uninitialized memory.

Comment: Ok, I see. The source `e.rightValue` is constructed, but the destination `this->rightValue` is uninitialized. So what do you think the fix for this is? It's not exactly like you can default-construct `leftValue` and `rightValue`.

Comment: @DavidFreitag You don't default-construct, you copy construct. e.g. `new (&rightValue) R(e.rightValue)`.

Comment: A *correct* copy constructor would use `::new`, `static_cast<void*>`, and `std::addressof`.

Comment: @T.C. Why the `static_cast<void*>` in particular?

Comment: Because `::operator new(size_t, int*)` etc. are not reserved?

Comment: can you provide an example where 
`::new (static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(leftValue))) L(e.leftValue);`
would behave differently to
`new (&leftValue) L(e.leftValue);`

Comment: @Gaetano `struct L { void operator&(); };`